# Number of permutations with element at certain position?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How do you calculate the number of permutations of a set of elements? Lets say we have elements A,B,C,D,E,F. What would be the number of possible arrangement with C at the leftmost position? And no repetitions are allowed.

Comment: **Hint:**  If C is in the leftmost position, how many ways can you place the A?  Once you have placed both A and C, how many ways can you place the B?  Continue.

Comment: It sounds like we need to subtract 1 from the 6 elements, and use the factorial of that.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1.5!=120$ ways,where $1$ is for $A$ and others $5!$ ways